# Why compiler thinks I haven't named the type for a vector var?

Tags: c++, c++11, types

I'm trying to define in `card.h` some vectors modelling a card game. I separate card ranks into the vectors `number_ranks` and `non_number_ranks`, and want to declare a `const vector<Rank> ranks` that combines both of the previously mentioned vectors:

```
// "card.h" file contents (top level).
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum class Rank {one = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight,
                nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};
const vector<Rank> number_ranks {
    Rank::one, Rank::two, Rank::three, Rank::four, Rank::five,
    Rank::six, Rank::seven, Rank::eight, Rank::nine, Rank::ten};
const vector<Rank> non_number_ranks {
    Rank::jack, Rank::queen, Rank::king, Rank::ace};

vector<Rank> _tmp (number_ranks);
// ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW.
_tmp.insert(_tmp.end(), non_number_ranks.begin(), non_number_ranks.end());
const vector<Rank> ranks (_tmp);
```

However I get this compiler error on the commented line:

```
card.h|16|error: ‘_tmp’ does not name a type
```

However I clearly define the type of `_tmp` on the line just before the erroneous line:

```
vector<Rank> _tmp (number_ranks);
```

Why does the compiler think I haven't named the type?

Comment: I'm guessing this code is not inside any function, its global, so the compiler don't understand he needs to call a function.

Comment: Note that you should [avoid using leading underscores on identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for the tip. I'm trying to mark the var like that to show it's not public and that it shouldn't be used outside of this header file. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you define global variable with `static` keyword, compiler uses internal linkage and it will hide it from other compilation units. And you shouldn't define variables in header files, put only declarations or type definitions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executive statements should be put inside a function, such as:

```
vector<Rank> _tmp(number_ranks);

int main() {
    _tmp.insert(_tmp.end(), non_number_ranks.begin(), non_number_ranks.end());
}
```

Or you can define a special function for it:

```
vector<Rank> get_ranks() {
    vector<Rank> tmp(number_ranks);
    tmp.insert(tmp.end(), non_number_ranks.begin(), non_number_ranks.end());
    return tmp;
}

const vector<Rank> ranks = get_ranks();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I get the compiler error `redefinition of 'int main()'` in file `main.cpp`, because this file does `#include "card.h"`. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: @NewWorld You can define another function in `card.h` to do it.

Comment: If I use the code in your second code sample the compiler throws `multiple definitions of get_ranks()`. I'm not sure exactly why this happens (the file includes header guards), but if I move the `get_ranks()` implementation to `card.cpp`, and instead only *declare* that function in `card.h` then it compiles successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't call a function from the top level**.

Any function call should made from within a function.
The following works *(live: https://ideone.com/MPFhhK)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum class Rank {one = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight,
                nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};
const vector<Rank> number_ranks {
    Rank::one, Rank::two, Rank::three, Rank::four, Rank::five,
    Rank::six, Rank::seven, Rank::eight, Rank::nine, Rank::ten};
const vector<Rank> non_number_ranks {
    Rank::jack, Rank::queen, Rank::king, Rank::ace};

vector<Rank> _tmp (number_ranks);

const vector<Rank> ranks (_tmp);        // **ERROR ON THIS LINE**


void initialize(){
    _tmp.insert(_tmp.end(), 
    non_number_ranks.begin(), non_number_ranks.end());
}


int main(void) {
    initialize();
    for( auto i=0;i<_tmp.size();i++)
        std::cout<<(unsigned int)_tmp[i]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. At the start this was an improvement over @songyuanyao's answer, but it still suffers from the same `redefinition of 'int main()' in file main.cpp` problem like I had with his answer.